# correct way to access class method in callback [prototype]

Tags: javascript, class, callback, prototypejs

I'm using prototype 1.7 and building a class that will essentially take a list of divs and builds a tab interface.

```
var tabs = Class.create({
    initialize: function(container, options) {
        this.options = Object.extend({
            // additional options
            tabsRendered: null,
        }, options || {});

        // init code

        if( this.options.tabsRendered ) {
            this.options.tabsRendered();
        }
    },

    // additional methods

    setCurrent: function(link){
        //adds a .current class to tab clicked and its corresponding section
    }
};

new vtabs( 'products', {
    tabsRendered: function(){
        if( window.location.hash != "" ) {
            var link = $$( 'a[href$="' + window.location.hash + '"]');
            this.setCurrent(link);
        } 
    }
});
```

My question relates to my **tabsRendered** custom callback. When the callback runs, `this.setCurrent(link)` does nothing.

If I pass **this** into the callback, my custom callback works as expected.

```
if( this.options.tabsRendered ) {
    this.options.tabsRendered(this);
}
```

My guess is that passing **this** into the callback is not best practice. So, how would I allow access to a method from within a callback?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `tabsRendered` is *unbound*. With Prototype you'll have to bind anonymous functions using `bind()`. After `// init code` do:

```
if (Object.isFunction(this.options.tabsRendered))
  this.options.tabsRendered = this.options.tabsRendered.bind(this);
```

After that you can call `this.options.tabsRendered()` and within that once-anonymous function, `this` will refer to the right object. For details on binding see [the Prototype API docs](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Function/prototype/bind/).

**EDIT:** As commented: it's correct that anonymous functions aren't the only ones affected. It's the `this` from the scope from which *a function* was defined.

Comment: +1, though it doesn't matter whether the function is anonymous or not, that has nothing whatsoever to do with binding. Also, `bind` is only one of several ways to do it (though it's a good one). For more on `this` and ensuring you preserve it: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html and http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html

Comment: Thank you goreSplatter, your suggestion helped a lot. Curiously, "Prototype.isFunction(this.option.tabsRendered)" did not work. In fact, it caused the script to stop executing.

Comment: Oh gosh. I meant `Object.isFunction`. I edited. Thanks for accepting.